# Spring Java based config not scanning my controller mappings

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat8

I have created a simple Hello controller class with java based configuration as shown below, but it is not mapping the request URI(i.e. **/sayHello**) while starting the the application. Hence when I request "http://localhost:8080/helloMvcWithJavaConfig/sayHello" we are getting **Http-404 error.**

**Why Spring context is not mapping my controller URI while starting the application?**

Below is my code:

**Project Structure:**

[image]

***controller:***

```
 package com.baji.mvc.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class Hello {

    @RequestMapping(value="/sayHello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String sayHello(ModelMap mm){
        mm.addAttribute("wishes", "Hello!");
        return "welcome";
    }

}
```

***welcome.jsp***

```html
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
 pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>HelloWorld page</title>
</head>
<body>Greeting : ${wishes}
</body>
</html>
```

***WebInitilizer.java***

```
    package com.baji.mvc.config;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class WebInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer{

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{SpringContextConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{SpringContextConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {

        return new String[]{"/"};
    }

}
```

***SpringContextConfig.java***

```
    package com.baji.mvc.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.baji.mvc")
public class SpringContextConfig {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {

        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        viewResolver.setPrefix(".jsp");

        return viewResolver;
    }

}
```

While starting the application I am getting below message on **Tomcat console:**

```
    Jan 31, 2018 9:06:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin;C:\Baji\softwares\apache-maven-3.5.0\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\salt;C:\Users\baji.shaik\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\baji.shaik\AppData\Local\Programs\Fiddler;C:\Users\baji.shaik\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;.
Jan 31, 2018 9:06:19 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:helloMvcWithJavaConfig' did not find a matching property.
Jan 31, 2018 9:06:19 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Jan 31, 2018 9:06:19 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Jan 31, 2018 9:06:19 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Jan 31, 2018 9:06:19 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Jan 31, 2018 9:06:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 716 ms
Jan 31, 2018 9:06:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jan 31, 2018 9:06:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.0-RC1
Jan 31, 2018 9:06:20 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Jan 31, 2018 9:06:20 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Jan 31, 2018 9:06:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 996 ms
```

***pom.xml***

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.baji</groupId>
    <artifactId>helloMvcWithJavaConfig</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <springframework.version>4.3.7.RELEASE</springframework.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: can you post your folder/package structure? Is your controller in a sub package of the main Spring class which loads your application, so that Spring can find your controller during the component scan.

Comment: sure it is: http://localhost:8080/helloMvcWithJavaConfig/sayHello not http://localhost:8080/sayHello? Or are you deploying your app not to the embedded tomcat?

Comment: Yes, it is localhost:8080/helloMvcWithJavaConfig/sayHello only. But anyway even  localhost:8080/sayHello also not working.

Comment: Updated the project structure in my post so please refer

Comment: You are using '@Controller' so you should add '@RequestBody' or '@ResponseBody' in your methods or just use '@RestController' instead

Comment: no @RestController is for REST Endpoints, here we want to send View templates to the browser,

Comment: its MVC not REST. We no need to add @RequestBody/@ResponseBody

Answer (score 0):

In your SpringContextConfig.java

```
viewResolver.setPrefix(".jsp");
```

It should be

> welcome.jsp

not

> .jspwelcome

Change to `viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");`

Comment: yes, its type issue. I just corrected to viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp"); But still same issue.

Comment: Did you add the below to the launch configuration of the tomcat server in eclipse.

 -Djava.library.path=[tomcat_home]\bin

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are getting  `Http Status 404 -/WEB-INF/jsp/welcome.jsp`

if so, most of your configurations are correct besides the misspelled 
   `viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");`

In addition to that change, i recommend you to change the class `SpringContextConfig` to extend `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`

I believe if you want to customize any spring mvc components you have extend to `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`.

Comment: Even after extending WebMvcConfigurerAdapter also it is not working

Comment: Interesting the log is missing the bootstrap of Spring Dispatcher Servlet,

INFO: 1 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'

Comment: did you create project with proper maven artifactId of 'maven-archetype-webapp'?

Comment: I knew it's been like 2years. Any update on this. Even I am facing the same issue.